# Filter Out Empty Lines on Paste?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange, mobx, onkeydown

I have 2 scenarios, for a search box.

**Scenario 1**

User pastes in some data into the box, 1 search per new line.

**Scenario 2**

User enters in each search line by using "shift + enter" to create new lines.

**Example paste data**

```
1

2

3

4

5

7



8






9



10
```

When they paste in this above data, I want to remove all blank lines. I can do this with filtering, but this has the side effect of "shift + enter" not working.

```
  // creates how many lines text area should be
  pastedData = event => {
    var clipboardData = event.clipboardData.getData('Text');

    var count = clipboardData.split('\n').length;
    if (count > 1) {
      this.rowCount = count;
    }
  };

  @action
  onChange = event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const splitValues = value.split('\n');

    this.rowCount = splitValues.length;

    if(this.rowCount > 100){
       this.searchValue = splitValues.slice(0, 100).join('\n'); 
    }else {

      this.searchValue =  value;
      // if I do this instead, this will remove all empty lines but shift + enter will not work anymore.
      //this.searchValue = splitValues.filter(x => x).join('\n');
    }

  };

  @action
  onKeyDown = event => {
    if (event.key == 'Enter' && event.shiftKey) {
      // make text area bigger.
      this.rowCount = this.rowCount + 1;
    } else if (event.key == 'Enter') {
      //submit form
    }
  };

 // switches between an normal text box and textarea is more than 1 line is entered.
  {this.rowCount === 1 ? (
    <input
      autoFocus={true}
      className="input"
      type="text"
      name="searchValue"
      onPaste={this.pastedData}
      onChange={this.onChange}
      onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}
      value={this.searchValue}
    />
  ) : (
    <textarea
      autoFocus={true}
      className="textarea"
      name="search-area"
      rows={this.rowCount}
      value={this.searchValue}
      onChange={this.onChange}
      onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}
    />
  )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want the removal of new lines to happen when the user pastes something, it's best you use the `onPaste` (instead of `onChange`) [synthetic event provided by React](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#clipboard-events), exclusively for this activity. The `onChange` fires each time the input element registers a change in its value, be it by pasting or direct input by a user. You may use both in conjunction if the need arises.

Comment: So would I use both then OnPaste and OnChange(for shift+enter?) Do you have an example of both working together?

Comment: It would be of immense help if you provide us with a jsfiddle with your whole code for us to fiddle with.